# Does script developed on Appium for browser automation work on Android, iOS devices as well as desktops?

Tags: appium, seetest

I am trying to find out how much can Appium support for automation.

1. Do same script work on mobile as well as desktops ?
2. Does it have some way of providing devices on cloud like seetest?
3. Does it support native apps on both android and iOS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. Appium suports only mobile(iOS as well as Android) app automation
2. No. But using RemoteDriver you can achieve that e.g. Sauce labs
3. Yes. Appium supports native, web as well as Hybrid apps on iOS and Android platform

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. If by that you mean can you write a test suite that will work for both mobile devices and browsers.

   Appium's library adds `AppiumDriver` and two implementations of this: `AndroidDriver` and `IOSDriver`

   `Appium Driver` is an implementation of Selenium's `WebDriver` which can be used to write test suites for browsers.

   I have written test suites (in java) that work both on browsers and devices using Appium.
2. No, its just a framework. You can run it on simulated devices, or real ones (either over USB or wifi).
3. Yes, Appium actually has more features for native apps (swipes etc.).

Hope this helps,
Liam

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, if your app architecture is same for both iOS and android, then you can use locators like name, class name or ID which works on both platforms. Appium doesn't support desktop, only mobile.
2. No, but there are many cloud integrations are available in the market like Sauce labs where they use emulator on their cloud. But if you want to use real devices, you can use services like "Test Object" which provided good integration with appium.
3. Yes, it does support both iOS and android but there are some limitations for both the platforms which you would explore when you actually start using it based on your requirements.